# Where does Webmin store the root MySQL password?

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, webmin

If I change my root password for MySQL, Webmin prompts me to re-enter it so that it "knows" the password. Where is Webmin storing this password at?

[image: the prompt]

Answer (score 3):

```
/etc/webmin/mysql/config
```

Its the line that starts with `pass=`

> https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/mysql/config

If you're entering it into this file manually, it needs to be in plain text.

Note that this doesn't affect mysql's password, just webmin's login credentials to the mysql service.

Comment: Its been a while since I've used Webmin, but if you do change a configuration, you likely will need to restart Webmin service.

Comment: tested, works, just do: cat /etc/webmin/mysql/config | grep pass